# OPUS file code, how to open

Tags: audio, codec, opus

Hey I got the following file ( http://www.filedropper.com/opusfile )
Which is a .txt file containing OPUS audio code. How do I proceed and play this file?

Convertig to OPUS and using VLC player gives an error for me. Anyone with some tips?

Comment: File is only 35 kb... Are you sure it is a sound file?

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming file with `.opus` or `.ogg` extension and open in VLC, Chrome, or Firefox.